# Vue.js 2.0 same component rendering on one item but not another

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.4

I am building a Q&A website much like stackoverflow, where you can `vote` a `question` or `answer`. To simplify I kept the code for voting up.

This is the `vote` component is used on both `question` and `answer` components.

```
<template>
  <div class="vote">
    <h4 @click="voteUp">
      <i :class="{'fa fa-chevron-circle-up' : votedUp>-1, 'fa fa-chevron-up': votedUp==-1 }"></i>
    </h4>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['votes','item'],
    computed:{
      votedUp() {
        return _.findIndex(this.votes, {user_id: this.$root.authuser.id});
      }
    },
    methods:{
      voteUp() {
        axios.post(this.$root.baseUrl+'/vote_item', {item_id:this.item.id,item_model:this.item.model,vote:'up'})
             .then(response => {
                _.isEmpty(response.data) ? this.votes.splice(this.votedUp,1) : this.votes.push(response.data);
              })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is the `question` component that uses `vote` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="question">
    <h1>{{ question.title }}</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <vote :votes="question.votes" :item="item"></vote>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-11 pb-15">
        <p>{{ question.body }}</p>
        <comment-list :comments="question.comments" :item="item" ></comment-list>
      </div>
    </div>
    <answer v-for="answer in question.answers" :answer="answer"></answer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['question'],
    data(){
      return {
        item:{ id:this.question.id, model:'Question' }
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is the `answer` component that uses `vote` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="answer row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 mt-20">
      <vote :votes="answer.votes" :item="item"></vote>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <h3>{{ answer.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ answer.body }}</p>
      <comment-list :comments="answer.comments" :item="item" ></comment-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['answer'],
    data(){
      return {
        item:{ id:this.answer.id, model:'Answer' }
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```

**THE ISSUE**

Voting up works fine and changes the state of both `question.votes` and `answer.votes`, but it only renders the HTML of `answers`. I have to refresh to see the upvote on `question`. Also in Vue developper tool console, `answer.votes` get refreshed automatically while I need to hit the vue refresh button to see `question.votes` taking the new vote into account (but still no HTML rendering).

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

As you can see, you can also `comment` on `question` and `answer`, and this is working fine on both because I used a different approach to `$emit` an event. Maybe this is a solution to my answer, but what I really want to know is **why the functionnality in `vote` is working on `answer` and not on `question`**.
Thanks!

Comment: Aren't using Vue in development mode? You shouldn't be changing/mutating `props`. Like in `vote` component - `this.votes.push`.

Comment: Yes I am using Vue in dev mode. How do you suggest I do it instead?

Comment: Then you should have a `warn` from Vue in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vote` component should not mutate `props`. Mutate a local copy:

```
export default {
  props: ['votes','item'],
  data() {
    return { votesCopy: [] };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.votesCopy = this.votes.slice();
  },
  computed:{
    votedUp() {
      return _.findIndex(this.votesCopy, {user_id: this.$root.authuser.id});
    }
  },
  methods:{
    voteUp() {
      axios.post(this.$root.baseUrl+'/vote_item', {item_id:this.item.id,item_model:this.item.model,vote:'up'})
           .then(response => {
              _.isEmpty(response.data)
                ? this.votesCopy.splice(this.votedUp,1)
                : this.votesCopy.push(response.data);
            })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But I still don't understand why the component should not mutate props. Can you please explain? Why would I copy and burden memory when it's more efficient to change the prop?

Comment: I guess [this discussion](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/4669/dealing-with-the-mutating-props-anti-pattern) explains better than I can.

Comment: It seems that the correct way to keep everything in sync is emitting events to change the parent's state. Your solution works and is more code-friendly (all voting logic stays in vote component) but creates an unsynced state between parent and child states. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: One last question: why did you slice votes in mounted() ? I tried it with data(){ return { votesCopy: this.votes; } } and it works

Comment: Well, ok then. It's my way to create an array copy.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker, Seems you master vue.js. I need you help. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454027/how-to-add-a-loading-icon-while-searching-vue-js-2